# How to Combine Big Arrow with Implied Arguments in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arguments

Is it possible to combine big-arrow syntax with implied argument? The code below fails:

```
var DoBigArrow = () => arguments[0];          
alert(DoBigArrow('Hello'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not expose an `arguments` object to their code.

From the docs,

> arguments.length, arguments[0], arguments[1], and so forth do not
>   refer to the arguments provided to the arrow function when called. 
>   Instead, arguments is simply a reference to the name in the enclosing
>   scope.

Even though your code is equivalent to:

```
var DoBigArrow = function(){
    return arguments[0];
}
```

In this case, argument refer's to the anonymous function's implicit variable binding, and hence returns the `argument` used to invoke the function.

In the case of Arrow functions, it is simply a reference to the name in the enclosing scope. You could wrap the function, thus creating an 'enclosing scope', so that the `arguments` point to the enclosed function's implicit arguments:

```
function wrapper(){
    var DoBigArrow = ()=>arguments[0];
    return DoBigArrow(); 
}

console.log(wrapper("hello")); //prints hello.
```

In most cases, an alternative would be to use [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: this may be closer to my OP, meaning everyone who voted up the other answer might not have understood my OP. Thx for explaining about "enclosing scope". of course i'd like to do this without a wrapper, otherwise it's more typing, not less. So i guess it's the wrapper that gives us access to `arguments`? thx

Comment: @johnywhy - welcome. yes. It is the enclosing scope.

Comment: where you say `var arguments = 42`, that's *not* the built-in implied `arguments` parameter, is it? You're just using the same name "arguments", correct?

Comment: Right. If you use Nodejs like wrapper to compile your code and without the arguments variable, it would simply print {}, which is the first argument to the Nodejs module that encloses our code.

Comment: Using the wrapper as you did does give the big-arrow fx access to the *actual* `arguments` parameter, which is great, and answers the OP. But, re-using the name `arguments` in your scoping example makes your answer confusing-- i thought that was your answer. i understand now that you showed that only to demonstrate enclosing scope, which is very helpful. I just would have used some other non-confusing variable name, like `MyArgs`. Your wrapper does indeed give access to the built-in implied `arguments` parameter, which is awesome. Thx!

Comment: @johnywhy - oh. Sorry for the confusion. It was to demonstrate that if you declare a variable named arguments in an enclosing scope, it would take precedence over the enclosing scope's implied arguments.

Comment: ok, i understand, but that goes just a bit beyond the 'scope' of the OP. Would have been clearer to put that at the end of your answer, if at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a ["Rest" parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to capture implied arguments.

```
var DoBigArrow = (...args) => args[0];          
alert(DoBigArrow('Hello'));
```

Comment: I changed your link because the question is about JS, not TS.

Comment: @MarkReed TypeScript

Comment: not sure i understand your example. It looks like you're declaring the arguments in the function's parameter list `(...args)`. The implied arguments i posted about are available to the function even with an empty parameter list. Can you show your example with an empty parameter list? if not, then this does not answer my OP. thx!

Comment: i looked at the linked article-- so you literally use 3 dots?

Comment: @johnywhy Right, the 3 dots are part of the syntax for declaring the open-ended rest parameter that captures all the "rest" of the parameters in an array. So `args` in the example behaves the same as `arguments` in a traditional JS function.

Comment: You do show how to achieve similar results, but it does require declaring a catch-all `...args` parameter. @BatScream's solution gives the BigArrow fx direct access to the actual implied `arguments` without anything in the parameter list. i might have to split the answer between this one and @BatScream's answer :)

Comment: i gave points to both answers, but awarded @BatScream's answer as the solution, cuz it answers the OP.